# Adding formula in specific row, with specific range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to ask if its possible to adding formula in each row, but with different spesific range in that row

[image]

in each yellow cell, I would like to add sum with :

1. Flora Total = SUM(B2:B3)
2. Fauna Total = SUM(B5:B9)

Is there any possibility to do that ?

I've tried to define the total of flora and the total of fauna
but I don't know to apply the vba for looking up if its flora or its a fauna

Comment: If you add an attribute to a separate column with the grouping, you could use standard approach like subtotaling or pivoting.

Comment: Is the table keep on changing size ? I mean, currently based on your image, you say `I would like to add sum with : Flora Total = SUM(B2:B3), Fauna Total = SUM(B5:B9)`. But after one hour, the size of the table is not like in the image anymore,.... so what you want after one hour about the total range, is not the same anymore with the range you said one hour ago. Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma it changes..
maybe one hour later I might add 2 new rows "Pine & Coconut Tree" and the formula will be at B6 and going like this =Sum(B2:B5)

Comment: This is how I would do it. **[THE SIMPLEST WAY] ** **1.** Select range B4:E4 **2.** Then press the CTRL key and then select B9:E9 **3.** Press ALT and then press = key and you are done. This will insert the formula in the blank cells. **[THE SUBTOTAL WAY] ** **1.** Insert a temp column in Col B. Name it "Type". Specify whether it is Flora or Fauna in Col B. **2.** Delete all rows which have "Total" word in Col A. **3.**  Use the Subtotal Feature to add the sum formula in the relevant colums. You can choose that in the Subtotal dialog box. **4.** Hide (not delete) Column B.

Comment: If it is you who add/insert a new rows, must it to be a vba ? Because you can just write the formula in the yellow area. As long as you insert new data by inserting the whole row, the formula will change automatically.  Please CMIIW.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged vba, and you've asked for vba to do this.. so here is a solution using vba. Some (most!) might call this overkill.

The following code scans the sheet and looks for the edges of the table before starting. Because of this, column A and row 1 need to be empty other than for this table - like your screenshot.

It then examines each cell of the table and if the left-most cell ends with the word "Total", it creates a formula to sum up from the last subtotal down to the cell above the formula.

```
Sub try_this()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long, y as Long, lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
    Dim last_subtotal as long
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
    
        lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For x = 2 To lastcolumn
            last_subtotal = 1
            For y = 2 To lastrow
                If Right(.Cells(y, 1).Value, 5) = "Total" Then
                    .Cells(y, x).Formula2 = "=sum(" & .Cells(last_subtotal + 1, x).Address & ":" & .Cells(y - 1, x).Address & ")"
                    last_subtotal = y
                End If
            Next
        Next
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Each time it is run, it will overwrite the formula before so can be used to 'correct' formulae that have become incorrect due to a user inserting rows in the wrong place etc. You could even perhaps use an event to ensure they're re-written all the time if you wanted full over-kill.